# Can all the unknown functions in a system of n first-order ODEs be expressed as the solution of an ODE of order up to n involving only that unknown?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of $n$ first-order differential equations of the form

$$x_1'=f_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$
$$x_2'=f_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$x_n'=f_n(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$

where the $x_i$ are the unknown functions. If a given $f_i$ is dependent on more than just $x_i$, is it always possible to decouple that equation so that we arrive at one of the form

$$x_i^{(r)}=g_i(x_i,x_i',\dots,x_i^{(r-1)})$$

for $r\leq n$?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat which statement is unclear?

Comment: Look up the Taken's theorem, what you are searching for is a continuous, differential variant. It proposes that there might be a single ODE of order $2n+1$ that can be used to parametrize the system solutions (if the initial values are right, which numerically they almost certainly never are).